# How can I install my own Python package in Azure Web App Service Linux environment?

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-python-sdk, azure-linux

I deployed my Python Django project to Azure Web Service Linux environment, and found an error most likely caused by the version of Azure's own Python version (see this post [Azure Text to Speech Error: 0x38 (SPXERR_AUDIO_SYS_LIBRARY_NOT_FOUND) when deploying to Azure App Services Linux environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72117202/azure-text-to-speech-error-0x38-spxerr-audio-sys-library-not-found-when-deplo) ). However, I cannot seem to find a way to upload my own Python package (3.10) to Azure Web Service Kudu site. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, This is not possible, the latest python runtime available in the Linux web app is 3.9

[image]

and in the other question, The default Linux Kudu page has a minimum number of features available when compared to windows and so you cannot directly drag and drop your zip file. If you need to install more components or language runtimes, you just need to use Kudu SSH terminal using `apt-get install <packages>`.

Also, try checking [Configure a Linux Python app for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python)

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.10 is now supported on App Service, so for this particular problem, you can update the configuration to Python 3.10.